advice on BLE service architecture for sharing data between mobile app and ESP32
Hi there Stackoverflow community!
I'm going to start a BLE application with the ESP32 microcontroller. I will need to send 3 different types of data back and forth between a mobile app and the ESP32.
My question isL what is the best BLE architecture to do this? Should I create 2 services RX/TX and just send the data with an attached byte to know the type? Or should I create 3 services for each type of data?
I feel the RX/TX is easier but I would like the advice of more knowledgeable people. Thanks a lot in advance

If the data sending mechanism itself is exactly the same regardless of data type, use one service and include the data type in the data itself. There is no need to have duplicated services with the same functionality just because you send different kinds of data. You can have one TX characteristic and one RX characteristic in the same service.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
